# Reference for finite groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I can't read the book (Huppert. B, Endliche Gruppen, 1967).  I want to know if there is an English version of this book. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope, there isn't one.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertram_Huppert) cites a later one: Finite Groups II, III (with N. Blackburn, Springer, 1981/82). [Google Books URL](https://books.google.de/books/about/Finite_Groups_II.html?id=t2zpCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Thank you sir, but I need the first part I

Comment: Even if there is not an English version. all important results are available in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no English translation of this book, and there are currently no plans for a translation.

The sequels Finite groups II and III are written in English. Many of the results in Endliche Gruppen I are available in other textbooks as well. However, I think for some topics it is the only textbook source.